# Windows 10 - Error 1051 Stop Control has been sent to a service that other running services are dependent on

Tags: service, windows-10

I have ServiceA, ServiceB, and ServiceC.  ServiceB depends on ServiceA, ServiceC depends on ServiceB.

Dependency chain:

ServiceA <- ServiceB <- ServiceC

When I open windows services, then click on ServiceA and hit restart, I get an error:

Error 1051 Stop Control has been sent to a service that other running services are dependent on

The problem is that windows attempts to stop ServiceB before ServiceC.

This setup works in pre-Windows 10 systems.  In pre-Windows 10, ServiceC would be stopped first then ServiceB then A.

I have tried altering the order in which I set the dependencies.  I have tried creating a servicegroup and setting the startup order in the registry under GroupOrderList.  Nothing has any effect, and the restarting always picks the same order and fails.

From powershell, I can run restart-service ServiceA -force, and all services restart correctly without an error.

This appears to be an issue with the Windows service manager.

How can I ensure the services are stopped in the correct order?